# Screen wake - go to home screen

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep-wake

The apple watch has "On screen wake show last app" with a time limit that means if the watch is unused for a period of time, go back to watch mode.

I've found this so useful in avoiding distractions that I'd like to find out if iOS has something similar.

I want it to go to the first page of the home screen if it's been inactive (asleep) for more than a few minutes.

Is there a way to do that?

I recognize that a quick swipe from the bottom will do this, but my problem is getting distracted with what I was working on awhile ago when my desire is to check my calendar, email, or something else.  I'd prefer the phone to handle it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible as a setting on iPhone. You may want to consider sending [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) concerning this.